# Android: Open a link in browser upon boot

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to open a link by android default browser on boot (startup)? without having to right code just by playing with settings?

I am trying to set a ulr, like http://google.com to be opened upon the reboot of my android device.

Another words,  when I turn off and turn back on my android device this address to open on the browsers and appear on the screen on my android device without I have to manually open the browser and enter this address.

Is there a way to do this without having to write android code?

I know it is possible in windows just by placing a shortcut to that url in the startup directory, but in android is there such a thing

Comment: I believe in Chrome you can save a link to the homescreen, like a shortcut. You'd still have to press the icon on reboot, but it will open the right URL for you. It's in the menu, "Add to home screen"

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Automate app' for this. It is very powerful. And the content view in the app should help for your requirement